# Суммировать и вывести произведение двух матрицы 3 на 3.

Tags: java

Java. 
Нужно создать две матрицы 3 на 3 вывести их сумму и произведение. Они заполнены случайными числами от 0 до 99.

```
   int[][] matrixA;
    matrixA = new int[3][3];
    for (int c = 0; c <= 99; c++) {
        for (int d = 0; d <= 99; d++) {
            rand.nextInt();
        }
    }
            System.out.println();

            int[][] matrixB;
            matrixB = new int[3][3];
            for (int c = 0; c <= 99; c++) {
                for (int d = 0; d <= 99; d++) {
                  rand.nextInt();
                    System.out.println(matrixA[c][d]+matrixB[c][d]);
                    System.out.println(matrixA[c][d]*matrixB[c][d]);
```

Проблема именно в matrix*[c][d], то есть в последних двух строках. Когда в массивах пишу цифры (то есть matrix*[3][3] - тоже проблемы.
Если есть и

Answer (score 0):

Если матрицы размером 3, то куда полезет обращение к 99-й строке или элементу?

```
matrixA = new int[3][3];
matrixB = new int[3][3];

 for (int c = 0; c <= 99; c++) {
  matrixA[c][d]+matrixB[c][d]
```

> то есть matrix*[3][3] -

А какой последний индекс в такой матрице?

Answer (score 0):

1) Матрицы по условию вашей задачи имеют размер 3 х 3, и именно так вы их инициализируете (`matrixA = new int[3][3]`). Это значит, что они имеют по три строки с индексами от 0 до 2 включительно, и в каждой из них по три элемента с индексами от 0 до 2 включительно. Потом в двойном цикле, где переменные `c` и `d` меняются в диапазоне от 0 до 99 каждая, вы пытаетесь обратиться к элементам своих матриц: `matrixA[c][d]+matrixB[c][d]`. Почему вы надеетесь, что массив из трех элементов будет содержать 4-й элемент, 5-й и так далее до 99-го включительно?

2) В цикле (опять от 0 до 99) вы, видимо, генерируете 10 000 случайных чисел в диапазоне от -2147483648 до 2147483647 (хотя из вашего кода не видно, что такое у вас `rand`, так что остается только догадываться). Зачем? Как вы используете эти случайные числа? В массивы вы их не записываете.

3) К тому моменту, как вы пытаетесь использовать матрицы, они у вас заполнены нулями, поскольку ничего другого вы в них не записали. Если бы у вас могло бы что-то вывестись на консоль, то вывелись бы одни нули, т. к. `0 + 0 == 0` и `0 * 0 == 0`.

4) В задаче требуется вывести сумму и произведение матриц. Если матрицы одинакового размера, то да, сумма матриц -- это матрица, состоящая из сумм элементов. Но произведение матриц -- это вовсе не набор поэлементных произведений элементов матриц.

В общем, впечатление такое, что вы очень смутно представляете, как работают программы и что означают их операторы. Я бы сильно советовал почитать какой-нибудь учебник по программированию для начинающих. Ну и какие-то начала линейной алгебры почитать, про матрицы.